# Accessing and Setting Map Options (Zoom)

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can you please take a look at following link and let me know how I can reset (Return Map to default Zoom 8) by clicking a button on the Map?
http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/cbTx5/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `map` variable outside `initialize` and call `map.setZoom(zoo)`.
Here is a fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/cbTx5/2/

Edit - fixed the demo

Answer (score 1):

The map will change the zoom level when the `zoom_changed` event is triggered. When you call setZoom(value) this event is triggered automatically.

If you want to have more control over when this happens you can always say:

```
$('.classname').click(function(){
  map.zoom=8;
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed');
});​
```

which will have the same effect and is less elegant, but it gives a better overview as to what is happening.

For all the events that are triggered when the map is manipulated, check out this demo:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html